# CTRL+LMB does not work on DuckDuckGo Ad links

Tags: google-chrome, duckduckgo

By CTRL+LMB I mean holding down the Control key, and while it is depressed, clicking the left-mouse-button.

Here is a detailed screenshot:

[image]

I did a duckduckgo search for these keywords `bike phone mount waterproof hardcase` and the search results were displayed.  However, the first two results that have an "Ad" icon ([image]) do not click properly when I use CTRL+LMB, in that nothing happens at all.  But search results that do *not* have an "Ad" icon *do* open up in a new browser window upon CTRL+LMB.

I've tried this only on Google Chrome but on two separate operating systems (Xubuntu 20.04 and Microsoft Windows 10) both using fairly recent versions of Google Chrome.

I do not know if this is a regression. I do not know if this is the DuckDuckGo website playing games with how links are handled.  I just don't know, but what I do want to know is if there is anything I can do to turn that behavior off?

Comment: The website behaviour is likely the result of how it was designed and outside of your control

Comment: @John if so, and that sounds like a design flaw, because I don't see the advantage to blocking popping up links into new windows.

Comment: I use uBlock Origin, so I see no ads and cannot help you. I'm even surprised that someone really clicks on advertisements.